# Residue at a simple pole in terms of limits

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, residue-calculus, singularity

Let $f$ be a function analytic in the open disk $\Delta(0,r)$, for $r>1$, except for a simple pole at $z_0=1$. Show that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}f^{(n)}(0)/n!=-\operatorname{Res}(1,f)$.

What I have done so far is just compute the residue by definition which is $\operatorname{Res}(1,f)=\lim_{z\rightarrow1}(z-1)f(z)$ and have the Cauchy’s Integral Formula in hand which has the term $f^{(n)}(z)/n!$. Can anyone give some hints on how to do this? Thanks!

Comment: if the residue is $c$ then $f(z)+\frac{c}{1-z}$ has radius convergence greater than $1$ so its Taylor coefficients go to $0$; now if $f(z)=\sum a_nz^n$ what are the Taylor coefficients of $f(z)+\frac{c}{1-z}$?

Comment: @Conrad Got it! Thank you so much!

Comment: happy to be of help